# How do I set the CLASSPATH used by TextMate when I compile and run Java

Tags: java, classpath, textmate

Using TextMate I can compile and run the Java class in the current editor window by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> (practical when debugging simple code).

How can I modify the CLASSPATH used by TextMate to compile and run the code, so I can use external libraries?

Comment: could you share how you modified the class path. Did you append to the current class path or did you explicitly point it to the folder containing the external libraries you needed? Thanks!

Comment: @Yasky: I explicitly pointed out the jar-files that I wanted to use (colon-separated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TextMate 1.5, under Preferences, there is an Advanced Preferences pane. That has three tabs; the second is "Shell Variables". You can set a CLASSPATH there which TextMate will use.